# Why can't I connect to my PostGIS database?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, connection

It's the second time that I install PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extension and it runs as long as I don't restart the PC. After I have restarted the PC QGIS and PgAdmin4 can't connect to the database. How can I fix that?

I have PostgreSQL 9.6.1-1 and PostGIS 2.3.1 and Windows 7.

[image: error message pdAdmin 4]

[image: error message QGIS 2.18.1]

Comment: in QGIS, delete the connection to the database that is giving you this problem. and establish a new connection

Comment: if you installed it twice, your new install might be running on port 5433 where as your old one was running on port 5432. and if you connected your database through QGIS when your port was 5432 it cannot connect to the new database that is in port 5433

Comment: thats what happened to me

Comment: but yesterday it worked with port 5432... I haven't changed anything since then. I use the exact same parameters like yesterday, but today it doesn't work...

Comment: so your new download is still working on port 5432?

Comment: i would still disconnect and establish new connections...

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't work out. I tried 5432 and 5433.

Comment: Is the database actually running?  Have you set it up as a service to automatically start on PC reboot?

Comment: probably not... where can I set it up as a service?

Comment: honestly if it were me and did not have important table saved on my database and would literally uninstall QGIS and PostgreSQL and then reinstall everything

Comment: have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14485121/5158630)?

Comment: Ok, so I deinstalled postgres & postgis. I installed it again. It works. I restart my PC. It doesn't work.

Comment: In Windows, click on the Windows icon in the bottom left and search for "Services". Choose the result with the gear-like icon. Scroll down alphabetically and look for postrgesql. You should see status=Started, Startup Type=Automatic and Log On As = Network Service. You can right-click to change properties.

Comment: That was it, thanks Nate. Startup Typ is set to Automatic. At least I can start manually the postgreSQL service and than I can connect to the database via pgAdmin or QGIS. But the service doesn't start automatically when I reboot the PC.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to enable it as a windows service, or start it manually.

Windows services can be slightly tricky, I would first do the manual step of starting it via the CMD line as documented in this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881845/how-to-manually-configure-and-start-postgresql-on-windows

Also I believe that to install it as a service might be dependent on the PostgreSQL installer you used. The installer may have created a 'postgresql' user to run the service as.